# Use of ampscript in mobile outbound SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I want to know if is it possible to get mobile numbers from a data extension directly into journey builder send SMS activity. 
I have a data extension with 17 different fields one of them contains subscriber's cell phone number without COUNTRY CODE.

I want to send email and SMS to those subscribers via journey builder. It is mandatory to include country code in front of those numbers so I am not sure if this is something which can be done via journey builder or is it mandatory to include those subscribers first in a mobile connect list and then use them in outbound SMS .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, you'll need to create an import definition in MobileConnect and an Automation to import your Data Extension records as Mobile Connect contacts before sending an SMS. There was talk of Jouney Builder Send SMS activities creating the Mobile contact for you, but I am unaware of that update having taken place.